# Display SQL table in Microsoft Teams

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to display the contents of a specific SQL Server table in Microsoft Teams? On a wiki page or seperate tab or whatever, but it needs to be 'real time connected'. The alternative is exporting an Excel file and share that via documents. It works, but I hope this can be done more elegantly.

*Update for clarification*

I have a SQL server **srv**, with a database **z**.

This is the sql for the 'specific table' (named **a**) mentioned in the question above.

```
create table a(b int, c int)
insert into a values(1, 2)
insert into a values(3, 4)
```

We have a company wide usage of Microsoft Teams, so I have no idea how it's hosted. I am just a participant (team member) and have the ability to add tabs to our Teams site and Wiki. My goal is to display the contents of table **a** in database **z** at server **srv** on our Microsoft Teams site.

Comment: what have you tried so far ? Are you stuck with some code or do you get an error ?

Comment: @GuidoG: I am quite new on using Microsoft Teams, so I got stuck while trying to add content to an existing Wiki. Then tried adding a new tab, hoping that I could put some 'component' in that. As said, we have a working situation, with the Excel files, I just hope it can be enhanced and have no clue where to start.

Comment: if you want an answer than you will have to give us something to work on. All you told us is that you are stuck with adding something to a wiki. That is like calling a workshop and saying `my car does not do what I want it to do, but you may not look at it. Fix it now.`You dont expect an answer there either are you

Comment: @GuidoG: I think the title and first sentence in my question are quite specific... But, since I really hope for an answer, I'll add some more (hopefully useful) specifics to the question.

Comment: @Steef As an alternative what you can do is create a webpage,display the contents in the webpage and add that webpage as a Tab in Microsoft Teams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Srinivas Naidu, the solution is to put it all on a website and add that as an extra tab in Microsoft Teams. So I enabled the webserver on our SQL server and created a simple page using asp.net. Unfortunately that didn't work either, because Microsoft Teams only supports https urls...

Comment: It is possible to get free HTTPS certification though for your IIS projects, for example use Certify the Web if you want a GUI approach.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to convert the SQL into an Excel document and (schedule the task) then the document will auto update into teams (assuming you saved it on One Drive in the first place).